# $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(k+n)!} \frac{n}{k!}$

Tags: summation

> $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 
> \frac{n}{(k+n)!} \frac{n}{k!}} ~= ~?$

From numerical calculation, I believe the answer is $e^2$. 
However, I have no idea how to show this.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)? Hence I guess you could use it to rewrite the product of the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}$, which defines $e$, with itselft to somehow end up by your double sum.

Comment: Thank you for a comment! It was an important step to change the indices as like the Cauchy product.  @mrtaurho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $m=n+k$. Then the sum is
$$S=\sum_{k,m:0\le k\le m}\frac{(m-k)^2}{k!m!}
=\sum_{k,m:0\le k<m}\frac{(m-k)^2}{k!m!}.$$
By the symmetry of the summand in $(m,k)$, and the fact it vanishes
for $m=k$, this is half the sum over all $m$ and $k$:
$$2S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(m-k)^2}{m!k!}
=S_2S_0-2S_1^2+S_0S_2$$
where
$$S_j=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{m^j}{m!}$$
Obviously, $S_0=e$, but it's not hard to prove $S_1=e$ and $S_2=2e$. We get $2S=2e^2$.

Comment: Yes, the indices are different. No, the sums are equal. @Mason

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The crucial step was using symmetry! Your answer is very clear and impressive :)